# Reasonable Use of MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB already in my project but I am about to expand it and I wanted to see if this is a reasonable use of the document style collection model.

Basically I have a number of different types of electrical boards and I am modeling the wiring in them. My data set isn't massive so I'm not worried all that much about efficiency but I don't want it to be horrendous. So here is my layout:

I have 8 or so board types and I am planning on just putting all these into one collection, they have slightly different schema like this:

```
{
    "id_num" : "int",
    "Board Type" : "string",
    "Signal Name" : "string",
    "FPGA #" : "int",
    "FPGA Pin #" : "int",
    "FPGA Page" : "int",
    "FPGA Address" : "int",
    "Net Name" : "string"
 }

 {
    "id_num" : "int",
    "Board Type" : "string",
    "Signal Name" : "string",
    "Feedback Pin" : "int",
    "Pin Functions" : "array of strings",
 }              

 {
    "id_num" : "int",
    "Board Type" : "string",
    "Signal Name" : "string",
    "FSW Handle" : "string"
 }
```

I will have approx 5000 documents total so nothing major and I want to see if this is a reasonable way to build a single collection. I will mostly be querying by Signal Name so I didn't want to split them up into 8 collections and have to do 8 queries to get all the wires with a specific signal name. Are there any negatives to throwing it all into one collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is reasonable, fits into the MongoDB "flexible schema" theme.  However, consider what happens when the number of documents grows -- you only have 8 board types, so thats a poor indexing choice.  How many signal names are there?  Essentially, to gain the benefit of indexing, you need a lot of "diversity" in the values.  If the number of choices is limited, then MongoDB goes to the proper index, but then scans document by document all the documents that share the same index value.  Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Oh I wasn't going to index by board type that was going to be my division for collections. the signal name will be my index because it will be unique in each class any only one instance of it for each board type.

Comment: In that case, its OK.  When you retrieve a document, you will have to examine board type to figure out the kind of board you have retrieved. Good luck